# What is a good algorithm to load OBJ files for use with openGL?

Tags: opengl

For a small game, I'm trying to write an OBJ file loader for loading models for use with openGL.

One nice trait of the OBJ file format is that it can reuse the same vertices by referencing them by their index when defining faces. OpenGL in turn has vertex buffer objects (VBO's) that are organized in a similar way; there is one geometry data buffer and one index buffer.

VBO's do not have unlimited space, so they can only be filled up until `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES`, after which from what I understand you will end up with a serious performance penalty.

I have been looking for an algorithm that can fill these VBO buffers while maintaining reused geometry data from the OBJ as much as possible, while respecting the limit set by    `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES / GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES`.

Are there any good methods or algorithms for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)

Comment: Going over `GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES` limit won't give you serious performance penalty. It only will "slow" down `glDrawRangeElements` function to the speed of `glDrawElements`.

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko Given that I use java, that might then be easier as well as not a serious impact on performance.. Hm. I should run some tests on that. Thanks!

Comment: have you actually tested what GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES is on your computer.  I'm guessing its much higher than the size model you need to load anyway.  

Also, I did some tests a long time ago that found that you dont actually save that much space in the end for many models because of all the extra indices.  I wouldnt worry about it

Comment: @zacaj: yes, I did. it was 33k for both on my machine. One of the models that I want to use greatly exceeds that number (the file itself is about 80Mb). It does mean, however, reducing memory load could easily lead to saving several Mb of VRAM. I found that significant enough to try to find a way to accomplish that, but without results.

Comment: @Bartvbl Can you give the stats on actual vertex, uv, normal, and triangle numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retain the data from `.obj` vertices sharing. Here is the code to load data from `.obj` and generate vertices/faces for your vertex buffers:

```
int FaceIndex = 0;
int VertexIndex = 1;
int TextureVertexIndex = 1;

char Prefix[3];

float X, Y, Z;
int A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2;

while ( !IStream->Eof() )
{
    std::string Line = IStream->ReadLine();

    int NumRead = sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %f %f %f", Prefix, &X, &Y, &Z );

    if ( NumRead < 1 ) continue;

    switch ( Prefix[0] )
    {
    case '#':
        continue;
```

Generate individual vertex. These can be shared between multiple faces:

```
    case 'v':
        {
            switch ( Prefix[1] )
            {
            case 0:
                if ( NumRead != 4 ) continue;
                EmitVertex( VertexIndex++, vec3( X, Y, Z ), -1, -1 );
                break;
            case 't':
                if ( NumRead != 3 ) continue;
                EmitTextureVertex( TextureVertexIndex++, vec3( X, 1.0f-Y, 0.0f ) );
                break;
            case 'n':
                if ( NumRead != 4 ) continue;
                EmitNormal( VertexIndex, vec3( X, Y, Z ) );
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
```

Generate faces with texture coordinates using the indices:

```
    case 'f':
        {
            if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d", Prefix, &A1, &A2, &B1, &B2, &C1, &C2, &D1, &D2 ) == 9 )
            {
                A3 = B3 = C3 = 0;
                EmitTextureFace( FaceIndex, A2, B2, D2 );
                EmitFace( FaceIndex++, A1, B1, D1, -1, -1 );
                EmitTextureFace( FaceIndex, B2, C2, D2 );
                EmitFace( FaceIndex++, B1, C1, D1, -1, -1 );
            }
            else if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d", Prefix, &A1, &A2, &A3, &B1, &B2, &B3, &C1, &C2, &C3 ) == 10 )
            {
                EmitTextureFace( FaceIndex, A2, B2, C2 );
                EmitFace( FaceIndex++, A1, B1, C1, -1, -1 );
            }
            else if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", Prefix, &A1, &A3, &B1, &B3, &C1, &C3 ) == 7 )
            {
                A2 = B2 = C2 = 0;
                EmitFace( FaceIndex++, A1, B1, C1, -1, -1 );
            }
            else if ( sscanf( Line.c_str(), "%2s %d/%d %d/%d %d/%d", Prefix, &A1, &A2, &B1, &B2, &C1, &C2 ) == 7 )
            {
                A3 = B3 = C3 = 0;
                EmitTextureFace( FaceIndex, A2, B2, C2 );
                EmitFace( FaceIndex++, A1, B1, C1, -1, -1 );
            }

        }
        break;
    }
}
```