# OpenGL: Vertex attribute arrays per primitive?

Tags: c, opengl

I'm wondering if it's possible in OpenGL (via extensions or otherwise) to have an attribute array specified by the `glVertexAttribPointer`type functions that advances by one for every primitive (or N vertices) instead of one for every vertex?

For example, if I have an array of triangles which have a solid color currently I'm having to repeat the same color data for every vertex, what I would like instead is something along these lines:

```
struct pos {
    uint8_t x, y;
} positions[NUM_VERTICES];

struct col {
    uint8_t r, g, b;
} colors[NUM_VERTICES / 3];
```

Where one element of the `colors` array is reused for every 3 consecutive `positions` elements when both arrays are submitted to OpenGL with `glVertexAttribPointer` and renderered with a single `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, ...);`

I found the `ARB_instanced_arrays` extension, which provides the `glVertexAttribDivisorARB` function which seemed promising at first, but I don't think it works the way I've described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially an alternate form of [this question about multi-indexed rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices) (it's different, which is why I'm not calling it a duplicate). The simple answer is no. The less simple answer is to do the accessing and indexing yourself.