# Use different GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER for different attributes in one shader?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In OpenGL (OpenGL ES 2.0) can I use more than one GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER for different GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffers? I'm reading "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide", Chapter 6 "Vertex attributes, arrays and buffer objects", there is source example: there are several GL_ARRAY_BUFFER (for position, normal, texture coords) and one GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER ("used to store element indices").

While I was writing question, I got that I can't send more then one indices array to glDrawElements, so if I use buffers, maybe only last binded GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER is using for drawing. But what about memory saving (what is purpose of glDrawElements)? I will illustrate problem that I faced.

There are 2 arrays (as GL_ARRAY_BUFFERs) - 8 vertices and 6 normals

```
GLfloat gVertexPositions[] =
{
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f
};

GLfloat gVertexNormals[] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // top
    -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // right
    0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // left
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  // back
    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f  // front
};
```

2 arrays of indices (as GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFERs)

```
GLubyte gVertexPositionIndices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, // top
    2, 3, 0,
    0, 4, 1, // right
    1, 4, 5,
    5, 4, 7, // bottom
    6, 5, 7,
    2, 6, 7, // left
    2, 7, 3,
    1, 4, 2, // front
    2, 4, 5,
    0, 3, 4, // back
    7, 4, 3
};

GLubyte gVertexNormalIndices[] =
{
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0,
    2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 3,
    5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5,
    4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4
};
```

I set vertex attribute state

```
    glBindAttribLocation(program, ATTRIB_POSITION, "a_position");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, ATTRIB_NORMAL, "a_normal");

//.....

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_POSITION_INDICES]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLubyte) * 36, gVertexPositionIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_POSITION_DATA]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * 8, gVertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_NORMAL_INDICES]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLubyte) * 36, gVertexNormalIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_NORMAL_DATA]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * 6, gVertexNormals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_POSITION_INDICES]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_POSITION_DATA]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_NORMAL_DATA]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[VBO_NORMAL_INDICES]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_NORMAL);

    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Then draw

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

And screen is empty (because last GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER is using for "a_position" attribute, where all triplets have identical numbers)

All I want - program makes 36 vertices, sets their positions from gVertexPositions using gVertexPositionIndices and their normals from gVertexNormals using gVertexNormalIndices. I doubt that is possible, but I want to know exactly. And what will be the right way if that is impossible? Do I have to use 8*3 floats for positions, 36 bytes for indices and 36*3 floats for normals? So I can save memory only for position attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not too late, but what I do is set the normals on a per-vertex basis within the vertex array, then use the appropriate strides and buffer offsets when declaring the vertex attributes. Here's my code declaring the vertices and normals:

```
GLfloat BlockVertexData[144] = {

//Right side...  
//Vertices...            //Normals...        
 1.0f,  2.0f,  0.5f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //B
 1.0f,  2.0f, -0.5f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //F
 1.0f, -2.0f,  0.5f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //D
 1.0f, -2.0f, -0.5f,     1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //H

//Front side...
-1.0f,  2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, //A
 1.0f,  2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, //B
-1.0f, -2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, //C
 1.0f, -2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, //D

//Left side...
-1.0f,  2.0f,  0.5f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //A
-1.0f,  2.0f, -0.5f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //E
-1.0f, -2.0f,  0.5f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //C
-1.0f, -2.0f, -0.5f,    -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, //G

//Back side...
-1.0f,  2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, //E
 1.0f,  2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, //F
-1.0f, -2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, //G
 1.0f, -2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, //H

//Top side...
-1.0f,  2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, //E
 1.0f,  2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, //F
-1.0f,  2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, //A
 1.0f,  2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, //B

//Bottom side...
-1.0f, -2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, //G
 1.0f, -2.0f, -0.5f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, //H
-1.0f, -2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, //C
 1.0f, -2.0f,  0.5f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f  //D };

GLuint BlockIndicesData[36] = {

//Right side...
2, 0, 3,     0, 1, 3,

//Front side...
6, 4, 7,     4, 5, 7,

//Left side...
11, 10, 8,    8, 9, 11,

//Back side...
15, 14, 12,  12, 13, 15,

//Top side...
19, 18, 16,  16, 17, 19,

//Bottom side...
23, 22, 20,  20, 21, 23 };
```

And here's the code declaring the attributes:

```
// The stride shows that there are 6 floats in each row.
GLsizei stride = 6 * sizeof(GLfloat);
GLuint attribute;

attribute = glGetAttribLocation(program, "VertexPosition");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);

attribute = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "VertexNormal");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute);
// The sixth parameter indicates the buffer offset, so here there were 3 floats preceding it, so this indicates it.
glVertexAttribPointer(attribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (GLvoid *)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 3));
```

I know that this may occupy more memory, but maybe someone can come up with a better solution. This is what I can think of to solve your problem.