# VBO Lighting and Indexing

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I am having a little trouble getting my VBO to render normals correctly now that I am using indexing. I am pretty sure it is something wrong with my offset for the normal pointer, but the math seems to add up to me.

How I store the data:

```
struct MyVertex
{
    float x, y, z;        //Vertex
    float nx, ny, nz;     //Normal
};
```

Below is how I set up the VBO:

```
GLuint VertexVBOID, IndexVBOID;
glGenBuffers(1, &VertexVBOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(MyVertex)*NumOfV, &ModelV[0].x, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &IndexVBOID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*NumOfF*3, &ModelI[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

My render code:

```
if(UsingVBO == false)
{
    glRotatef(Timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() * 10, 0, 1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for(int i = 0; i < NumOfF*3; i+=3)
        {
            glNormal3f(ModelV[ModelI[i]].nx, ModelV[ModelI[i]].ny, ModelV[ModelI[i]].nz);
            glVertex3f(ModelV[ModelI[i]].x, ModelV[ModelI[i]].y, ModelV[ModelI[i]].z);

            glNormal3f(ModelV[ModelI[i+1]].nx, ModelV[ModelI[i+1]].ny, ModelV[ModelI[i+1]].nz);
            glVertex3f(ModelV[ModelI[i+1]].x, ModelV[ModelI[i+1]].y, ModelV[ModelI[i+1]].z);

            glNormal3f(ModelV[ModelI[i+2]].nx, ModelV[ModelI[i+2]].ny, ModelV[ModelI[i+2]].nz);
            glVertex3f(ModelV[ModelI[i+2]].x, ModelV[ModelI[i+2]].y, ModelV[ModelI[i+2]].z);
        }
    glEnd();
}
else
{
    glRotatef(Timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() * 10, 0, 1, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), 0);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (void*)(NumOfV*sizeof(float)));//Number of vertices times size of float
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NumOfF*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);//number of indices

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
}
```

Rendering without VBO:

[image: Pic1]

Rendering with VBO:

[image: Pic2]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)

Comment: Isnt the point of indexing to reuse vertices though? Thats what I got from here: [link](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/) - "In this tutorial, we introduce indexing, which enables to reuse the same vertex over and over again. This is done with an index buffer."

Comment: A vertex is not a position. A vertex *contains* a position, but that's not all it is. It has normals, colors, texture coordinates, or whatever attributes you want. Sharing vertices is very possible, but *not* if you're rendering a faceted object. The way you're doing. You need per-vertex normals, not face normals.

Comment: The normals are calculated to be vertex normals, not face normals. However, my non-VBO rendering code was rendering it in a normal-per-face fashion. I edited my post and fixed that. To sum up, there are the same amount of normals as vertices, with 1 normal to 1 vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (void*)(NumOfV*sizeof(float)));//Number of vertices times size of float
```

Your [offset is wrong](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_buffer_offset_and_stride) here. You're providing interleaved vertex data, so that the first three floats are your positions and the next three floats are the normals. Your base offset for normals is therefore 3 floats worth of bytes (to skip the position). `NumOfV` is the number of vertices *in your entire model*, not the number of floats for positions in your `MyVertex` data structure.

This is best done with [the `offsetof` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (void*)offsetof(MyVertex, x));
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(MyVertex), (void*)offsetof(MyVertex, nx));
```