# What is the difference between glVertexAttribDivisor and glVertexBindingDivisor?

Tags: opengl, vertex, opengl-4, vertex-buffer, vertex-attributes

I was looking for ways to associate attributes with arbitrary groupings of verticies, at first instancing appeared to be the only way for me to accomplish this, but then I stumbled up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169228/opengl-single-vertex-attribute-for-multiple-vertices) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171762/2036035) states :

> However what is possible with newer versions of OpenGL is setting the rate at which a certain vertex attribute's buffer offset advances. Effectively this means that the data for a given vertex array gets **duplicated to n vertices** before the buffer offset for a attribute advances. The function to set this divisor is **glVertexBindingDivisor**.

(emphasis mine)

Which to me seems as if the answer is claiming I can divide on the number of vertices instead of the number of instances.  However, when I look at [`glVertexBindingDivisor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexBindingDivisor.xhtml)'s documentation and compare it to [`glVertexAttribDivisor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribDivisor.xhtml)'s they both appear to refer to the division taking place over *instances* and not *vertices*. For example in `glVertexBindingDivisor`'s documentation it states:

> glVertexBindingDivisor and glVertexArrayBindingDivisor modify the rate at which generic vertex attributes advance when rendering multiple **instances** of primitives in a single draw command. If divisor is zero, the attributes using the buffer bound to bindingindex advance once per vertex. If divisor is non-zero, the attributes advance once per divisor **instances** of the set(s) of vertices being rendered. An attribute is referred to as **instanced** if the corresponding divisor value is non-zero.

(emphasis mine)

So what is the actual difference between these two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the actual difference between these two functions?

Modern OpenGL has *two* different APIs for specifying vertex attribute arrays and their properties. The traditional `glVertexAttribArray` and friends, where `glVertexAttribDivisor` is also part of.

With [`ARB_vertex_attrib_binding`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_vertex_attrib_binding.txt) (in core since GL 4.3), a new API was introduced, which separates the vertex format from the pointers. It is expected that switching the data pointers is fast, while switching the vertex format can be more expensive. The new API allows to explictely control both aspects separately, while the old API always sets both at once.

For the new API, a new layer of introduction was introduced: the *buffer binding points*. (See the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format) for more details.) `glVertexBindingDivisor` specifies the attribute instancing divisor for such a binding point, so it is the conceptual equivalent of the `glVertexAttribDivisor` function for the new API.

Comment: huh, am I miss-understanding that answer i linked then?  or where they just mistaken?

Answer (score 8):

OK, first a little backstory.

As of OpenGL 4.3/ARB_vertex_attrib_binding (AKA: where `glVertexBindingDivisor` comes from, so this is relevant), VAOs are conceptually split into two parts: an array of vertex formats that describe a single attribute's worth of data, and an array of buffer binding points which describe how to fetch arrays of data (the buffer object, the offset, the stride, and the divisor). The vertex format specifies which buffer binding point its data comes from, so that multiple attributes can get data from the same array (ie: interleaving).

When VAOs were split into these two parts, the older APIs were re-defined in terms of the new system. So if you call `glVertexAttribPointer` with an attribute index, this function will set the vertex format data for the format at the given `index`, and it will set the buffer binding state (buffer object, byte offset, etc) for the same `index`. Now, these are two separate arrays of VAO state data (vertex format and buffer binding); this function is simply using the same index in both arrays.

But since the vertex format and buffer bindings are *separate* now, `glVertexAttribPointer` also does the equivalent of saying that the vertex format at index `index` gets its data from the buffer binding at index `index`. This is important because that's not automatic; the whole point of vertex_attrib_binding is that a vertex format at one index can use a buffer binding from a different index. So when you're using the old API, it's resetting itself to the old behavior by linking format `index` to binding `index`.

Now, what does all that have to do with the divisor? Well, because that thing I just said is literally the only difference between them.

`glVertexAttribDivisor` is the old-style API for setting the divisor. It takes an attribute index, but it acts on state which is part of the buffer binding point (instancing is a per-array construct, not a per-attribute construct now). This means that the function assumes (in the new system) that the attribute at `index` fetches its data from the buffer binding point at `index`.

And what I just said is a bit of a lie. It *enforces* this "assumption" by directly *setting* the vertex format to use that buffer binding point. That is, it does the same last step as `glVertexAttribPointer` did.

`glVertexBindingDivisor` is the modern function. It is not passed an attribute index; it is passed a buffer binding index. As such, it does not change the attribute's buffer binding index.

So `glVertexAttribDivisor` is exactly equivalent to this:

```
void glVertexAttribDivisor(GLuint index, GLuint divisor)
{
  glVertexBindingDivisor(index, divisor);
  glVertexAttribBinding(index, index);
}
```

Obviously, `glVertexBindingDivisor` doesn't do that last part.