# Drawing vertices with glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

I want to draw some indexed vertices with glDrawElements. Their positions are stored inside an array. Also, I've got an array with an uncertainty value that is associated with each vertex. Originally, this array was not sorted, so the first uncertainty value of this array corresponded to the first position in my vertex positions array. I then had to sort the uncertainty array, so the values are stored in descending order. I also have an index array, which containts the orignal indices from the uncertainty array. My arrays are set up like this:

```
vertexPositionArray = {(0,0,0,1), (0,0,1,1), ..., (dimX, dimY, dimZ, 1)}
uncertaintyArray    = {1000.00, 989.20, 945.01, ...};
indexArray          = {76504, 65024, 3424, 3, 30491, 59123, ...};
```

Now...I would like to draw the vertices inside my positionsArray in a way, that the order is determined by the indexArray. So the first vertex to render would be the one with the position at index 76504 in the vertexPositionsArray and with an uncertainty value at index 76504 in my uncertaintyArray.

I hope you get the point, it's pretty hard to describe what I'm trying to do. My current code isn't producing the expected output. I guess I'm not really sure which array the glDrawElements method works on.

```
// Enable user defined "IN"-variables
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBufferObject);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexUncertaintyBufferObject);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndexBufferObject);

// Draw vertices
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, dimensionX * dimensionY * dimensionZ, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: So, the positions and uncertainty values are in different orders? (the nth vertex position does not correspond to the nth uncertainty value?)

Comment: yes, that's what I thought might be right...but I guess I have to sort the positions array as well, or let the uncertainty array unsorted and just use the IBO to render

Comment: Yeah, probably leaving both arrays unsorted would be best. If you do that, does everything work as you expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)