# How to transform texture of three.js to WebGL

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, webgl

I got two texture objects of position and normal, say,

```
var tx1 = gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( positionVariable ).texture;
var tx2 = gpuCompute.getCurrentRenderTarget( normalVariable ).texture;
```

which is calculated by `GPUComputationRenderer` from `three.js` (refer to the example `gpgpu/protoplanet` (1))

I want to transform it to a `WebGLBuffer` object for rendering, like:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tx1);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tx2);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

But the direct assignment is not OK.

I want to ask if there is a way to do it. The snapshot of the format of these two objects is shown as follows (tx1 is from threejs, and tx3 is from WebGL). Thanks.

(1) https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_protoplanet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy textures into buffers directly. Why not just use them as textures? Here's an example that renders positions out of a texture.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22009385/128511

Comment: Thanks very much. Then is there a way to transform that texture object generated by three.js to the WebGLTexture format generated by WebGL by `gl.createTexture();`? Sorry that I am not familiar with javascript. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know how to get a `WebGLTexture` from a `THREE.Texture`. I'd ask a separate question for that as in "How to I get a WebGLTexture from a THREE.Texture?"