# send data to shader per-index(not per-vertex)

Tags: indexing, three.js, webgl, fragment-shader

I have some nodes and edges with same position attribute.
I want to change color of edges on click event and I use a float vertex attribute for check activation in fragment shader and if it was 1 I will color that fragment to red.
But I have a problem, imagine a triangle , when I selecting two edge of it the active property for all three vertex changed to one and in this time the third edge will make red because both vertex of it are active.

So I want a way to set attribute per index and then I can use them for any edge Independently. is it possible? how?

**EDIT** :

my input is like this:

```
pos : [x0,y0,z0 , x1,y1,z1 , x2,y2,z2] // should use with indexing
index for pos : [0,2 , 1,2 , 0,1]
active [0,1,1,0,1,0] // should not use with indexing
```

with giving those inputs I want some output like this

```
pos : [x0,y0,z0 , x2,y2,z2 , x1,y1,z1 , x2,y2,z2 , x0,y0,z0 , x1,y1,z1]
active : [0,1,1,0,1,0]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: expand your geometry so no vertices are shared

Comment: it's my last choose

Comment: Your other option is to put your data in textures, then you can index however you want

Comment: I didn't understand your mean, can you give me a link about that? or explain more?

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988072/webgl-texture-coordinates-and-obj/22009385#22009385

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible - vertices have no connectivity information when they are shaded.

Comment: let me explain more. I have a geometry which I want to using some attributes of it with index and some without index like what I edited now

Comment: It's still not possible. You only have vertices, and all data has to be attached to a vertex. Indices and edges simply don't exist in the API as a data carrying construct.