# How to add vec2 for UV for texture mapping when using indices

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to apply texture mapping to my cubes but are unsure on how to proceed. Current I am using indices to avoid having to repeat vec3s to make a cube and a vertex array of the points and their normals like so:

```
// Cube data as our basic building block
       unsigned int indices[] = {
        10, 8, 0, 2, 10, 0, 12, 10, 2, 4, 12, 2,
        14, 12, 4, 6, 14, 4, 8, 14, 6, 0, 8, 6,
        12, 14, 8, 10, 12, 8, 2, 0, 6, 4, 2, 6
       };


       vec3 vertexArray[] = {
        vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),  vec3(-0.408248, -0.816497, -0.408248),
        vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f),    vec3(0.666667, -0.333333, -0.666667),
        vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f),    vec3(0.408248, 0.816497, -0.408248),
        vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f),   vec3(-0.666667, 0.333333, -0.666667),
        vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),    vec3(-0.666667, -0.333333, 0.666667),
        vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),     vec3(0.666667, -0.666667, 0.333333),
        vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f),     vec3(0.408248, 0.408248, 0.816497),
        vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f),    vec3(-0.408248, 0.816497, 0.408248),
       };

        // convert arrays to vectors
        std::vector<vec3> vertexArrayVector;
        vertexArrayVector.insert(vertexArrayVector.begin(), std::begin(vertexArray), std::end(vertexArray));

        std::vector<unsigned int> indicesVector;
        indicesVector.insert(indicesVector.begin(), std::begin(indices), std::end(indices));
```

I want to now apply textures to the cube but I am not sure how to add the use of a vec2 for UV when using indices. My creating of VBOs and VAOs like this if it helps:

```
GLuint vertexBufferObject;
    GLuint indexBufferObject;
    GLuint vertexArrayObject;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferObject);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexIndicesArray[0]) * vertexIndicesArray.size(), &vertexIndicesArray[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Upload Vertex Buffer to the GPU, keep a reference to it (vertexBufferObject)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPointsArray[0]) * vertexPointsArray.size(), &vertexPointsArray[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Teach GPU how to read position data from vertexBufferObject
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,                   // attribute 0 matches aPos in Vertex Shader
        3,                   // size
        GL_FLOAT,            // type
        GL_FALSE,            // normalized?
        0,                   // 0 stride
        (void*)0              // array buffer offset
    );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Teach GPU how to read normals data from vertexBufferObject
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,                            // attribute 1 matches normals in Vertex Shader
        3,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        0,
        (void*)sizeof(glm::vec3)      // normal is offseted a vec3 (comes after position)
    );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The vertex coordinate an the texture coordinates for a tuple with 5 components (x, y, z, u, v). If you have a vertex coordinate that is shared by the face but is associated to different texture coordinates, you need to duplicate a vertex coordinate. You must specify 1 attribute tuple for each vertex coordinate and texture coordinate combination required in your mesh.
It is not possible to specify different indices for the vertex coordinates and texture coordinates. See [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices) and [Why does OpenGL not support multiple index buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046585/why-does-opengl-not-support-multiple-index-buffering).