# use UV and normal indices in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opentk, opengl-4

Im working on a school project with OpenTK and c# and I want to render models from OBJ files.

However they contain separate indices for vertices, UVs and normals and my question is if there is a way in OpenGL 4 to use separate indices instead of just one index for everything.

I always can reorder the arrays for vertices, UVs and normals so they all work with just one index, however this would require extra vertices for the textures to map correctly and all 3 arrays would have to be the same size. This would use considerably more memory, especially with bigger models.

Comment: See [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices) and [Why does OpenGL not support multiple index buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046585/why-does-opengl-not-support-multiple-index-buffering)