# Wrap texture around a cylinder using index buffer object?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl

**Context:** Since the index buffer object allows me to prevent duplicating vertices and the texture buffer objects only applies to vertices, I seem unable to wrap the texture properly all the way around the cylinder (no vertices are mapped to the UV coordinates (1, 0) for example). It seems like I need to add an additional set of vertical vertices overlapping the first one but this messes with my calculation of the normals of the vertices.

**Question:** Is there a way to map texture coordinates to indices instead of vertices or something like that, so that the texture completely wraps around the rolled mesh?

Comment: You can have texture indices too. Read up about vertex attributes. See [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102389/how-to-implement-index-buffer-object-ibos-with-texture-coordinates-in-opengl) for example.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog You can't have separate indices for the texture coordinates. If 2 different texture coordinates for the same vertex position are needed., then the vertex coordinate itself has to be doubled and to be paired with both texture coordinates.

Comment: There is a Q/A in the OpenGL forum regarding this: [glDrawElements with multi indexing buffers](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181690-glDrawElements-with-multi-indexing-buffers). It seems that AMD proposed an extention to enable multi-indexing. (I just googled it as I remembered that somebody told me about this.) However, we haven't used it, and I'm not sure how "portable" this is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices)