# Using VBO to draw the cube by loading wavefront object

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront

I am required to Using VBO to draw the cube by loading  wavefront object.
by drawing the triangles.
here is the object:

```
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
f 2//1 3//1 1//1
f 4//2 7//2 3//2
f 8//3 5//3 7//3
f 6//4 1//4 5//4
f 7//5 1//5 3//5
f 4//6 6//6 8//6
f 2//1 4//1 3//1
f 4//2 8//2 7//2
f 8//3 6//3 5//3
f 6//4 2//4 1//4
f 7//5 5//5 1//5
f 4//6 2//6 6//6
```

I also have a cooler array filled by myself which equals to 3 times number of face which is 36 indices

```
float colours[] = {
    0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
    0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
    0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
    0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
    0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
    0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f,
    0.597f,  0.770f,  0.761f,
    0.559f,  0.436f,  0.730f,
    0.359f,  0.583f,  0.152f,
    0.483f,  0.596f,  0.789f,
    0.559f,  0.861f,  0.639f,
    0.195f,  0.548f,  0.859f,
    }
```

I store my vertices,normals,colours information into a array which is binding to VBO buffer:

```
 float* vbo = new float[78]
```

which is in the order of vertices|normals|colours which is  24indices|18indices|36indices, I have been test it works very well

I use another array to store the vertices indices information which is 36indices ,for example: f 2//1 3//1 1//1 I store as 2/3/1 in my array

```
 int *element = new int[36];
```

I have been test it works well ，I initial my vbo as follow:

```
 static void init(void){
 .......
Gluint vbo_id,index_id;

glGenBuffers(1,&vbo_id);
glGenBuffers(1,&index_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo_id); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,index_id);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vbo),vbo,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(element),element,GL_STATIC_DRAW); }
```

and my drawing is here

```
 static void display(void){
  .......
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo_id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,index_id);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,0);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,(void*)(24*sizeof(float)));//binding 
    glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,(void*)(42*sizeof(float)));

    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glArrayElement(element[i]);
    glArrayElement(element[i+1]);
    glArrayElement(element[i+2]);
    glEnd();

    }
    /* have try this one too:
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,3,GL_INT,0) */


    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    }
```

however there's nothing show on the screen. is my binding method correct, my instructor tells me when I draw with the indices , if I binding vertices and normals ,and colors correct , It will automatically matching by drawing with indices of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `vbo` is `float*`, so `sizeof(vbo)` is not the size of the array, where `vbo` points to, but it's the size of the pointer. See [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).
 Note, the 3rd parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) has to be the size of the buffer in bytes.

The size of `float* vbo = new float[78]` is `78 * sizeof(float)` or `78 * sizeof(*vbo)`
and the size of `int *element = new int[36]` is `36 * sizeof(int)` or `36 * sizeof(*element)`
But `sizeof(vbo)` is the size of the pointer to the array or the same as `sizeof(float*)`.

This means you have to change the code like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 78*sizeof(float), vbo, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(int), element, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The 2nd paramter of [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) has to be the number of indices and the 3rd paramter has to be `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, dependent on the data type of the indices:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

Note, you should prefer to use `unsigned int *` instead of `int*` for the data type of the index array (`element`).

---

Your assumption is wrong. You can't mix 24 vertex coordinates, 18 normal vectors and 36 colors, with differnt arrays of indices, directly in one [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).

The vertex attributes for each vertex position form a set of data. This means you have to create tuples of vertex coordinate, normal vector and color.

See further [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices/11148568#11148568)

I recommend to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and to do it somehow like this:

```
#include <vector>
```

```
// 8  vertex coordiantes: 8 * 3 float 
std::vector<float> v{
  -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
  -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
  -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
  -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
   1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
   1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
   1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
   1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f };

// 6  normal vectors: 6 * 3 float
std::vector<float> nv{
   -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f };

// 12 colors coordiantes: 12 * 3 float 
std::vector<float> c{
    0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
    0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
    0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
    0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
    0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
    0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f,
    0.597f,  0.770f,  0.761f,
    0.559f,  0.436f,  0.730f,
    0.359f,  0.583f,  0.152f,
    0.483f,  0.596f,  0.789f,
    0.559f,  0.861f,  0.639f,
    0.195f,  0.548f,  0.859f };
```

```
// 12 faces 3*2 indices/face: 12 * 3 * 2 unsigned int 
std::vector<unsigned int> indices{
    2, 1,    3, 1,    1, 1,
    4, 2,    7, 2,    3, 2,
    8, 3,    5, 3,    7, 3,
    6, 4,    1, 4,    5, 4,
    7, 5,    1, 5,    3, 5,
    4, 6,    6, 6,    8, 6,
    2, 1,    4, 1,    3, 1,
    4, 2,    8, 2,    7, 2,
    8, 3,    6, 3,    5, 3,
    6, 4,    2, 4,    1, 4,
    7, 5,    5, 5,    1, 5,
    4, 6,    2, 6,    6, 6 };
```

Create the vertex array data

```
// final vertex attributes 12 * 3 *(3 + 3 + 3) floats
// x0 y0 z0    nvx0 nvy0 nvz0    cr0 cg0 cb0
// x1 y1 z1    nvx1 nvy1 nvz1    cr1 cg1 cb1
std::vector<float> va; 

const unsigned int no_of_faces = 12;
for (unsigned int f=0; f<no_of_faces; ++f )
{
    for (unsigned int t=0; t<3; ++t )
    {
        unsigned int vi = indices[(f*3+t)*2]-1;   // vertex index
        unsigned int ni = indices[(f*3+t)*2+1]-1; // normal vector index
        unsigned int ci = f;                      // color index

        va.insert(va.end(), v.begin()  + vi*3, v.begin()  + vi*3+3); // insert vertex coordinate
        va.insert(va.end(), nv.begin() + ni*3, nv.begin() + ni*3+3); // insert normal vector
        va.insert(va.end(), c.begin()  + ci*3, c.begin()  + ci*3+3); // insert color
    }
}
```

Create the [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object):

```
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, va.size()*sizeof(*va.data()), va.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

Define the an arrays of generic vertex attribute data:

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 9*sizeof(*va.data()), 0 );
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glNormalPointer( GL_FLOAT, 9*sizeof(*va.data()), (void*)(3*sizeof(*va.data())) ); 
glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 9*sizeof(*va.data()), (void*)(6*sizeof(*va.data())) ); 
glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

Draw the array:

```
glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36 );
```

Preview:

[image: cube]

Comment: Hi,I follow your instruction, but it crashes ,it should use sizeof(*float) or sizeof(*va.data())? and it should be  glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 )? ;I test va has the right output.,