# How do I put a texture on my object?

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl, sdl-2, opengl-3

I'm trying to put a texture on my object (which is a 3D cube) but I'm not sure how to do it because I'm not getting the correct result. Also, I'm using SDL for this.

This is where I initialize everything:

```
void OpenGLWindow::initGL()
{
    .
    .
    .
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    shader = loadShaderProgram("simple.vert", "simple.frag");
    glUseProgram(shader);

    // ambient
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "objectColor"), 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.31f);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "lightColor"), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "lightPos"), 1, &lightPos[0]);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "viewPos"), 0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("container.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }

    stbi_image_free(data);

    // Set our viewing and projection matrices, since these do not change over time
    glm::mat4 projectionMat = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 10.0f);
    int projectionMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projectionMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, 1, false, &projectionMat[0][0]);

    glm::vec3 eyeLoc(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);
    glm::vec3 targetLoc(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 upDir(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::mat4 viewingMat = glm::lookAt(eyeLoc, targetLoc, upDir);
    int viewingMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "viewingMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewingMatrixLoc, 1, false, &viewingMat[0][0]);

    // Load the model that we want to use and buffer the vertex attributes
    //geometry.loadFromOBJFile("sphere.obj");
    geometry.loadFromOBJFile("cube.obj");

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*geometry.vertexCount()*sizeof(float), geometry.vertexData(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    GLuint texturebuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &texturebuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturebuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(geometry.textureCoordData()) * sizeof(glm::vec3), geometry.textureCoordData(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturebuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glPrintError("Setup complete", true);
}
```

I'm reading an .obj file which has the coordinates of the vertices, normals and textures already using a class which stores each coordinates in an appropriate vector;

for e.g. std::vector vertices; std::vector textureCoords; std::vector normals;

How can I send the values inside the texture's vector to the shader?

This is my vertex shader:

```
in vec3 position;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewingMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 transformedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewingMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = transformedPosition;
    FragPos = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(modelMatrix))) * position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
out vec4 outColor;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{
    float ambientStrength = 0.06;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    float specularStrength = 0.1;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor;
    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor;
    outColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

What should I do to put the texture on the object (3D cube)?

This is what I'm getting so far:

[image]

The texture doesn't appear on all faces and when zooming in or out, some red, green or blue lines appear on the surface.

Comment: *"I'm not getting the correct result"* - You have to be more specific. What exactly is the issue? How do you read the *.obj* file? See [How do I sort the texture positions based on the texture indices given in a Wavefront (.obj) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708275/how-do-i-sort-the-texture-positions-based-on-the-texture-indices-given-in-a-wave/51711080#51711080) and [Rendering meshes with multiple indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148567/rendering-meshes-with-multiple-indices/11148568#11148568)

Comment: I cannot get the texture on the object. I'm using a class which handles that, which I believe is the same as the method in the first link you posted. I have a vector which has all the texture coordinates. I think I should send that to the shader but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 3 types of vertex coordinates you need 3 [Vertex Shader inputs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs):

```
in vec3 a_position;
in vec2 a_uv;
in vec3 a_normal;
```

For each of these attribute you have define and enable an array of generic vertex attribute data by [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) respectively [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml). The index of the vertex attribute (which is the first parameter to `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer`), can be get by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml).

e.g.

```
GLint uv_inx = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "a_uv");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(uv_inx);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturebuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(uv_inx, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

But the modern way would be to define the vertex attribute indices in shader by useing [Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)), which makes the `glGetAttribLocation` calls superfluous:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 a_uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 a_normal;
```

You have to pass the attributes from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. The final vertex shader and input to the fragment shader may look like this:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 a_uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 a_normal;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewingMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 transformedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewingMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = transformedPosition;
    FragPos     = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0));
    Normal      = mat3(transpose(inverse(modelMatrix))) * a_normal;
    TexCoord    = a_uv;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec2 TexCoord;
```

To load and look up the texture in the fragment shader, you need a texture sampler uniform. See [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)).
To the sampler uniform you have to assign the index of the texture unit - see [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml).
In your case this is *0* for `GL_TEXTURE0` (which is default).

Texture sampler uniform in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
```

Setting texture unit 0 to the texture sampler uniform, in c++ code:

```
GLint tex_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_texture");
glUniform1i(tex_loc, 0); // 0 because of GL_TEXTURE0
```

Since GLSL version 4.2, this can done in shader code by a [Binding point](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points) qualifier:

```
layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_texture;
```

The fragment shader may look like this:

```
#version 420

out vec4 outColor;

in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;
in vec2 TexCoord;

.....

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 textureColor = texture(u_texture, TexCoord);

    ....
    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * textureColor.rgb;
    outColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

Of course you can "modulate" the object color and the texture corot by multiplying them:

```
vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor.rgb * textureColor.rgb;
```

Comment: Sorry for replying a bit late, I was away. So I just added everything in your answer but I'm getting this error: `Shader load error: error: linking with uncompiled shadererror: linking with uncompiled shader`
And I didn't add/remove anything more from any of my files.

Comment: Ok, I think the issue is that I'm using `#version 330 core` and you put `#version 420 core` and `#version 400 core` in the fragment and vertex shaders respectively. Is there a way to go around that?

Comment: I reverted back to `#version 330 core` and I'm simply using `uniform sampler2D u_texture;` instead of `layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_texture;`. That shouldn't really be an issue right?

Now everything compiles but my object's color changes to blue but the texture doesn't show up on the object. Am I missing something? I will update my `initGL()` where I initialize everything in my question above.

Comment: @pk123 As I mentiond in the answer, `layout (binding = 0)` is available since GLSL version 4.20. Since you use version 3.30, you have to delete `layout (binding = 0)`. Use only `uniform sampler2D u_texture;`. Since your texture is bound to texture unit 0, this will work. I changed the answer to clarify this.

Comment: yes its compiling without errors now. But the texturing is not correct. I've edited my question above. Please have a look if you can.

Comment: @pk123 This brings us back to the first comment, which I posted to your question above. See [How do I sort the texture positions based on the texture indices given in a Wavefront (.obj) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708275/how-do-i-sort-the-texture-positions-based-on-the-texture-indices-given-in-a-wave/51711080#51711080)

Comment: Thanks. But I doubt I will have time to do this now, especially for someone at my level. But thanks anyway :)