# Convert .obj+.mtl models to .ply format with vertex-color information

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, 3d, 3d-modelling, ply-file-format

I am trying to convert **thousands** of .obj + .mtl models of [ShapeNet](https://www.shapenet.org) to .ply format. However, as this dataset contains thousands of models, manually converting them is not the best solution. I've already tried many different solution such as using [ctmconv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ctmconv.1.html)  or [assimp](http://www.assimp.org/), but they all fail as to best of my understanding they cannot convert mtl to vertex color.

You can find two example of the model [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IQIl0EInpTIA-ONzru_C-iW5YVzQWxDa). Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: in 3D scanner obj files the vertex color is usually not stored in `mtl` but `obj` file itself.  For other models the `mtl` lighting coefficients can give you color ... so if your tools does not do it correctly write your own one that does it as should ... see [How do I sort the texture positions based on the texture indices given in a Wavefront (.obj) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722009/2521214) for some ideas ...

Comment: @csuo  Were you able to do this in some way ? I also want to achieve the same thing but could not find any script which can do it

Comment: @mascot, finally I tried in Blender, I merged all the meshes and export them with the format that I wanted. However, you should be careful with the textures, if you need them.

Comment: @csuo  Were you able to get the vertex colors also ?   I imported my obj file in blender (mtl file was also loaded), when I export it to .ply format. It does not give me vertex colors; only x,y,z coordinates and faces

Comment: @mascot, that is what I tried to mention. It is not straight forward, but I think that is more about learning how to export mtl to vertex color in Blender. Some tutorials can be already found in this matter, but as the vertex color was not my main objective, I did not spend much time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `meshlabserver`, the command-line version of [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) included in the same package. The command you want to use is:

`meshlabserver -i inputFilename.obj -o outputFilename.ply`

if you want to ensure that color-per-vertex is generated even if it is not present in the mtl file (because you have a color-per-material schema), just add the `-m vc` option at the end of the command.