# .OBJ OpenGL wrong render

Tags: delphi, opengl, 3d, wavefront, opengl-compat

anybody knows, why it happen? A try to render OBJ file with Opengl.

[image]

```
  // (0 - индекс вершины / 1 - индекс текстурной координаты / 2 - индекс нормали)
  for i := 0 to length(faces) - 1 do
  begin
    glBegin(faces[i].mode);
    Count := length(faces[i].data);
    for k := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      glNormal3fv(@normals[faces[i].data[k].normalIndex]);
      glTexCoord2fv(@texcoords[faces[i].data[k].texCoodIndex]);
      glVertex3fv(@vertexes[faces[i].data[k].vIndex]);
    end;
    glEnd();
```

Comment: already answered but see [How do I sort the texture positions based on the texture indices given in a Wavefront (.obj) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722009/2521214) for some more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wavefront OBJ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_OBJ) start at 1. So you have to subtract 1 from each index:

```
glNormal3fv(@normals[faces[i].data[k].normalIndex - 1]);
glTexCoord2fv(@texcoords[faces[i].data[k].texCoodIndex - 1]);
glVertex3fv(@vertexes[faces[i].data[k].vIndex - 1]);
```

Comment: Surprising that the code that parses the obj file doesn't make that adjustment

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's a common issue in many different wavefront parser in many languages.

Comment: It's almost as if the author of the parser never even bothered to write code to render the model!