# How do I index positions with different normals

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, wavefront

I can't seem to have a grasp on OpenGL VAOs and VBOs.

I am coding an OBJ Loader from scratch (BTW I am using LWJGL) and I can't seem to get the order of normals correctly. When I look at the OBJ File I notice that there are positions with different normals and the face contains index numbers for position, texture, and normals. I don't know how to order them properly so that my normals would be assigned into correct positions when the engine starts rendering.

Comment: In ur first suggestion, can I still use that technique if I want to use Element Buffers? since i am duplicating the positions for different normals (this is what i understood)

Comment: see [How do I sort the texture positions based on the texture indices given in a Wavefront (.obj) file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722009/2521214)